# Remove URL file extension but retain file structure?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like `http://example.com/dev/testSite/` where the root of the testSite is in the dev directory. I have that directory set up like:

```
testSite
-images/
--image.png
-css/
--style.css
header.php
footer.php
index.php
page.php
```

I have also included in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The first issue with this is instead of going to page.php like `http://example.com/dev/testSite/page/` it is instead redirecting to `http://example.com/page/`. Eventually this site will live at `http://testSite.com` so I assume this code is going to work correctly. In the meantime, is there any fast I can do to make it work in the dev environment? Something that I can change quickly when moving it to the production environment.

The second issue is that this is also altering the file structure of the files. For example, any code on page.php like `<img src="images/image.png">` is actually trying to find this image in `http://example.com/dev/testSite/page/images/image.png`. I suppose this .htaccess is making it behave as if I added the directory "page" instead of just hiding the extension.

There is no kind of framework or anything on the site so just regular php pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess should be like this in `/dev/` sub-directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php [L]
```

Then to fix relative paths in css/js you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/dev/testSite/" />
```

Comment: So I have moved the .htaccess to the /dev/ directory, however, base=/dev/ is not working. I have changed it to base=/dev/testSite/ and it seems to work for the css/js. The rewrite rules are still trying to redirect to example.com/page/ even with the base in the header and the .htaccess in the /dev/ directory instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Looks like I'm going to have to go with directories and absolute paths. Bleh. Thanks for the help though. This does the same, navigating to path.php results in example.com/path/ instead of example.com/dev/testSite/path/ or whatever it's supposed to be. Thanks again.

Comment: What URL is not working now? Have you tried clearing your browser cache?